# Is there a preferred framework for non-standard, non-native kiosk style GUI applications?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I've been toying with wxPython, but it seems mostly geared at 'standard' applications -- things with native looking file menu systems and toolbars and whatnot.

My needs are pretty simple. I just need to be able play some mp3s, show some images, and be able to package it down to an .exe and .dmg. Also, being able to play an small mp4 would be grand.

Unfortunately, I realize that there is no definitive answer to this question, and therefore doesn't exacltly fit the stack overflow format, but a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: sounds like a screensaver... is that correct?

Comment: Have you at least tried googling for the various things you're asking for?

Comment: @Inerdial - I have indeed. And the list of frameworks is daunting. So I thought I'd ask for an experienced opinion to help me cut through the fluff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pyqt/pyside/Qt has the newer declarative QML which seems to have a application geared to a kiosk type interface. You can basically design something in Photoshop and use it as your custom UI

Comment: Ah, that sounds pretty neat. This is the first I've heard of QML. This seems like it may be the way to go based on what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Comment: Dont forget to hit the green check mark if this solves it for ya!

Answer (score 3):

[Pygame](http://pygame.org/) is the usual choice for *fully* custom UIs.

[image]